# Change Power App Form in Response to Sharepoint List View Selection

Tags: powerapp

I have created a PowerApps customized list form that is linked to my Sharepoint List. I set up different views in the Sharepoint List, but I don't see a way to change the linked PowerApps list form to match the view fields. I found an [article](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/separate-custom-forms/) explaining how to make separate forms to create, show or edit the list item and then write formulas in SharePointIntegration control to navigate to the screen and set the form in correct mode based on user inputs.

The formulas looked like this:

OnNew – Set(SharePointFormMode, "CreateForm"); NewForm(CreateItemForm); Navigate(CreateScreen, ScreenTransition.None)

OnEdit – Set(SharePointFormMode, "EditForm"); EditForm(EditItemForm); Navigate(EditScreen, ScreenTransition.None)

OnView – Set(SharePointFormMode, "ShowForm"); ViewForm(ShowItemForm); Navigate(ShowScreen, ScreenTransition.None)

Does anyone know how I could alter these formulas to direct users to different forms based on the sharepoint list view that they choose? Or whether there is another way to alter the PowerApps form in response to view selection?